# Good .NET libraries for working with JSON data?

Tags: javascript, .net, json

I am currently trying out [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/), and it seems to work well.

Any other good JSON libraries for .NET?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474377/json-library-for-c-sharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Jayrock](http://jayrock.berlios.de/) works well and transparently turns your objects to and from JSON objects providing they have a public constructor. It also creates the script for you so you can just call your web service like a Javascript class.

#### Example:

```
public class Person
{
  public string Name { get;set;}
  public int Age { get;set; }

  public Person() { }
}

public class MyService : JsonRpcHandler
{
   [JsonRpcMethod("getBob")]
   public Person GetBob()
   {
       return new Person() { Name="Bob",Age=20};
   }
}
```

And the Javascript:

```
var service = new MyService();
var result = service.getBob();
alert(result.name); // JSON objects are camel-cased.
```

Answer (score 5):

There is the [JavascriptSerialiser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) which is used by asp.net mvc and asp.net ajax. Also there is the [DataContractJsonSerialiser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx) used by WCF. The only problem I have encountered with the JavascriptSerialiser is that it uses funny way to serialise dates, which I do not think will parse into a javascript date. But this is easyly solved by this snippet

```
    public double MilliTimeStamp()
    {
        DateTime d1 = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
        DateTime d2 = DateTime.UtcNow;
        TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(d2.Ticks - d1.Ticks);

        return ts.TotalMilliseconds;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

The class [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) from the [System.Web.Script.Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.aspx) namespace provides good JSON serialization/deserialization support.