# .NET Libraries to work with JSON

Tags: .net, asp.net, javascript, json, jayrock

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Good .NET libraries for working with JSON data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986361/good-net-libraries-for-working-with-json-data)

We are currently writing our ASP.NET pages using c# and .NET 2.0 framework and we are about 4 months out from upgrading to .NET 3.5 framework. Meanwhile we have a very client-side JS heavy page to push out in 2 months. We are currently looking at [JayRock](http://jayrock.berlios.de/) to handle our client-to-server service methods invoking with JSON data. One of the very nice things about JayRock is the dynamically generated client-side proxy js to instantiate and call the server side methods.

Does anyone have experience with JayRock? Pros? Cons? Or other libraries that can help us accomplish the similar task?

Also, since we are upgrading to .NET 3.5 by the end of the year, and .NET 3.5 has JSON serialization capabilities. Should we switch from JayRock once we upgrade?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you can install [the ASP.NET AJAX Extensions](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=ca9d90fa-e8c9-42e3-aa19-08e2c027f5d6&displaylang=en) with 2.0, it has the same JSON serialization functionality that 3.5 has built in.

Comment: You can have a closer look at ... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx