# JSON library for C#

Tags: c#, json

Does Microsoft provide any library to work with JSON in C#? If not, what open source library do you recommend?

Comment: Do you mean consuming, creating or both?

Comment: Both consuming and creating. Thanks

Answer (score 77, accepted):

[JSON.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx)

Comment: What's the advantage of using JSON.NET over System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer?

Comment: it allows you to use as class property, instead just serialize strings, for one... there are way more..

Comment: Don't use JavaScriptSerializer its around 40x slower than most other JSON serializers I've benchmarked.

Comment: latest JSON.NET build has some issues with the .NET Framework 3.5. Recoverable by using install .NET Framework 3.5 SP1. However if you cant change to .NET Framework 3.5 SP1, don't use JSON.NET

Comment: I have tried JSON.NET at bit, and they have a problem when it comes to polymorphism, as I see it. For JSON.NET to be able to deserialize an object that inherits, JSON.NET requires there typ be a property named "$type" that contains the type name, however, I think it requires the FULL type name, and thats not the good stuff when you have a JAVA/Android-thing on the other end.

Comment: could have been better if you describe how its good and your experiences with it as well

Comment: Microsoft MVC4 has JSON.NET as a dependency, so it seems a de facto Microsoft standard.  NuGet package is called Newtonsoft.Json

Answer (score 19):

You should also try my ServiceStack [JsonSerializer](http://www.servicestack.net/mythz_blog/?p=344) - it's the fastest .NET JSON serializer at the moment [based on the benchmarks of the leading JSON serializers](http://www.servicestack.net/benchmarks/NorthwindDatabaseRowsSerialization.100000-times.2010-08-17.html) and supports serializing any POCO Type, DataContracts, Lists/Dictionaries, Interfaces, Inheritance, Late-bound objects including anonymous types, etc.

Basic Example

```
var customer = new Customer { Name="Joe Bloggs", Age=31 };
var json = customer.ToJson();
var fromJson = json.FromJson<Customer>();
```

Note: Only use Microsofts JavaScriptSerializer if performance is not important to you as I've had to leave it out of my benchmarks since its up to **40x-100x** slower than the other JSON serializers.

Answer (score 14):

The .net framework supports JSON through JavaScriptSerializer. Here is a good example to get you started.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace GoogleTranslator.GoogleJSON
{
    public class FooTest
    {
        public void Test()
        {
            const string json = @"{
              ""DisplayFieldName"" : ""ObjectName"", 
              ""FieldAliases"" : {
                ""ObjectName"" : ""ObjectName"", 
                ""ObjectType"" : ""ObjectType""
              }, 
              ""PositionType"" : ""Point"", 
              ""Reference"" : {
                ""Id"" : 1111
              }, 
              ""Objects"" : [
                {
                  ""Attributes"" : {
                    ""ObjectName"" : ""test name"", 
                    ""ObjectType"" : ""test type""
                  }, 
                  ""Position"" : 
                  {
                    ""X"" : 5, 
                    ""Y"" : 7
                  }
                }
              ]
            }";

            var ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            ser.Deserialize<Foo>(json);
        }
    }

    public class Foo
    {
        public Foo() { Objects = new List<SubObject>(); }
        public string DisplayFieldName { get; set; }
        public NameTypePair FieldAliases { get; set; }
        public PositionType PositionType { get; set; }
        public Ref Reference { get; set; }
        public List<SubObject> Objects { get; set; }
    }

    public class NameTypePair
    {
        public string ObjectName { get; set; }
        public string ObjectType { get; set; }
    }

    public enum PositionType { None, Point }
    public class Ref
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class SubObject
    {
        public NameTypePair Attributes { get; set; }
        public Position Position { get; set; }
    }

    public class Position
    {
        public int X { get; set; }
        public int Y { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is good code, how could I one of the classes to get the results back? For instance ObjectName to output to a textbox with the results 'test name'? I have tried 'test = GoogleTranslator.GoogleJSON.NameTypePair.ObjectName' messagebox.show(test)

Answer (score 7):

If you look here, you will see several different libraries for JSON on C#.

http://json.org/

You will find a version for LINQ as well as some others. There are about 7 libraries for C# and JSON.

Answer (score 5):

Is this what you're looking for?

[System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the system.web.script.serialization namespace (i think you will need .Net 3.5)

Answer (score 2):

To give a more up to date answer to this question: yes, .Net includes JSON seriliazer/deserliazer since version 3.5 through the System.Runtime.Serialization.Json Namespace:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json(v=vs.110).aspx

But according to the creator of JSON.Net, the .Net Framework compared to his open source implementation is very much slower.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question, Microsoft does ship a DataContractJsonSerializer: see msdn [How to: Serialize and Deserialize JSON Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try the Vici Project, Vici Parser. It includes a JSON parser / tokeniser. It works great, we use it together with the MVC framework.

More info at: http://viciproject.com/wiki/projects/parser/home

I forgot to say that it is open source so you can always take a look at the code if you like.