# C# export / write multidimension array to file (csv or whatever)

Tags: c#, arrays, xna, xmlserializer, multidimensional-array

Hi Designing a program and i just wanted advise on writing a multiDim array to a file.
I am using XNA and have a multidimension array with a Vector3(x, y, z)'s in it.

There are hundred thousand if not millions of values, and i want to be able to save them in a file (saving the game level). I have no bias to one idea, i just need to store data...thats it! All the other game data like player stats etc etc i am using XMLSerializer and its working wonders.

Now i was playing with xml serializer alot and have learn that you cannot export MultiDim Arrays... so frustrating (but i am sure there is a good reason why - hopefully). I played with Jagged's with no luck.

Used  System.IO.File.WriteAllText  then quickly relised that is only for string... daahhh

Basically i think i need to go down the BinaryWrite method, re-writing my own serializer, over even try running a sql server to host the masses of data... stupid idea? please tell me and can you point me in the write direction. As i primarily have a web (php) background the thought of running a server that syncs data / level data is attractive to me... but might not be applicable here.

Thanks for anything,

Mal

Answer (score 1):

You can just serialise the lot with the built-in .NET serialisers provided the objects in the array are serialisable (and IIRC Vector3s are).

```
void SerializeVector3Array(string filename, Vector3[,] array)
{
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    Stream s = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Create);
    bf.Serialize(s, array);
    s.Close();
}

Vector3[,] DeserializeVector3Array(string filename)
{
    Stream s = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open);
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    Vector3[,] array = (Vector3[,])bf.Deserialize(s);
    s.Close();
    return array;
}
```

That should be a rough template of what you're after.

Comment: Thanks for your response, i will be trying your way and the suggestion from Zasz tonight. really appreciate both your quick answers!

Comment: Ok tried this way out, worked well, only one problem... the file size is 1gb and growing... flippen heck... might need to re-think storing vector3 like this. given that i am trying to output a file thats array[10000,5000] ... :P

Comment: Interesting, aren't you running out of main memory? Try to look for strategies, alternate workflows that will have a lesser memory footprint, and especially profile your app, in these kinds of situations.

Comment: Yea your exactly right, i am now re-thinking the way the program has to run and store data. I thought of maybe cutting up into chunks but  really its still a silly idea cause file size still the same, but maybe it loaded the chunks at different times etc... I think for now i will work with small sets of data and keep the rest running in the ram. The interesting thing is that i can run the program with [10000,5000] easily and smoothly... given that i prolly need to check the ram usage :P Thanks again guys you have been very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try Json Serialization? Json has less noise than XML, occupies less space when written to file especially if you do so without indenting, etc. It does not have trouble with arrays, dictionaries, dates and other objects as far as my experience with it goes.

I recommend using [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx) and if not, then look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474377/json-library-for-c)

If Json.net finds it difficult to serialize a library class with many private & static variables, then it is trivial to write a POCO class and map the library class essential properties to your POCO and serialize and map the POCO back and forth.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, ill take a look at JSON tonight.

Comment: Ok side by side JSON is smaller file size then the first answer above (BinaryFormatter();) but its still fairly large file size... needs to start looking at compressions. Again thanks for your help guys