# JSON with C# and without ASP.NET

Tags: c#, json, parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JSON library for C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474377/json-library-for-c-sharp)

I know it is possible to parse JSON with ASP.NET, but for my code, I need to parse JSON in c# without ASP.NET

Google has been unable to help as it only shows ASP.NET related pages

Are there any libraries that help with this?

Comment: Json.NET is propably the most popular choice these days - http://json.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx).  It's a great library and it's used by a number of products/frameworks/projects out there.

You can download it from CodePlex here -- http://json.codeplex.com/

I've used it on a number of projects and can vouch for it.  It's simple to use and pretty extensible if you need it to be (for custom serialization/deserialization scenarios) both within and outside of ASP.NET projects.

Hope this helps.  Good luck!!