# Deserialize JSON into string

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, json, serialization

How can I deserialize:

```
{
    "data": [
        {"ForecastID":8587961,"StatusForecast":"Done"},
        {"ForecastID":8588095,"StatusForecast":"Done"},
        {"ForecastID":8588136,"StatusForecast":"Done"},
        {"ForecastID":8588142,"StatusForecast":"Pending"}
    ]
}
```

to

```
class RawData
{
    public string data { get; set; }
}
```

So, I just want to have

```
[
  {"ForecastID":8587961,"StatusForecast":"Done"},
  {"ForecastID":8588095,"StatusForecast":"Done"},
  {"ForecastID":8588136,"StatusForecast":"Done"},
  {"ForecastID":8588142,"StatusForecast":"Pending"}
]
```

as value of property data of `RawData`'s class instance.

Comment: Why can't you create a class to hold the data (`int ForecastID`, `string StatusForecast`)? What you describe is not "deserialization" - it is string parsing.

Comment: @oded Result of this function would be deserialized with complex logic further.

Comment: Most serializers just don't work like that (only do part deserialization). You would either need to hook into the serializer or write your own serializer to do this. I would think that doing a full deserializtion would be easiest (you can re-serialize the bits you want later on).

Comment: Try a [JSON library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474377/json-library-for-c-sharp) or [`JavaScriptSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx).

Comment: @Oded I just need to check is whether data field is exist and do other checks on that

Answer (score 4):

Using [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/)

```
var obj = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
var newJson = obj["data"].ToString();
```

or using built-in [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
var dict = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(json);
var newjson = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(dict["data"]);
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't prefer to use external packages for that.

Comment: @kseen JSON's been around since 2006 http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt?number=4627 and the JSON.net project started pretty quickly after that http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx. The idea of writing your own routines to serialise or deserialise JSON correctly and confidently seems foolhardy and a waste of time. I just want to wholeheartedly support LB's suggestion.

Comment: @L.B Is not serializing back will produce performance penalty?

Answer (score 2):

It would have made far much more sense to deserialize this JSON structure to:

```
public class Forecast
{
    public IEnumerable<ForecastData> Data { get; set; }
}

public class ForecastData
{
    public int ForecastID { get; set; }
    public string StatusForecast { get; set; }
}
```

which is pretty trivial with the [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) class that's built into the framework:

```
string json = "your JSON data here";
IEnumerable<ForecastData> data = new JavaScriptSerializer()
    .Deserialize<Forecast>(json)
    .Data;
```

or if you don't want to define models you could do that:

```
dynamic result = new JavaScriptSerializer().DeserializeObject(json);
foreach (var item in result["data"])
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", item["ForecastID"], item["StatusForecast"]);
}
```