# C# rpg read stats from file

Tags: c#, string, file-io

So I have a text file with a few lines formatted like this:

> Name=Fighter, Strength = 10,Cunning = 4, Willpower = 2, Magic = 5, Constitution = 10, Health Formula = 250, Stamina Formula = 200, Magic Formula = 100

This file has no extension is utf-8 encoded and the filename is Classes.

currently it has 4 lines where the stats change between each "name"  these are base stats so they will never change unless I do it manually.

I use 2 files to reference this information.
Entity.cs:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    namespace RpgLibrary.CharacterClasses
    {
    public enum EntityGender { Male, Female, Unknown }
    public abstract class Entity
    {
    #region Vital Field and Property Region
    protected string entityType;
    protected EntityGender gender;
    public string EntityType
    {
        get { return entityType; }
    }
    public EntityGender Gender

         {
        get { return gender; }
        protected set { gender = value; }
    }
    #endregion
    #region Basic Attribute and Property Region
    protected int strength;
    protected int dexterity;
    protected int cunning;
    protected int willpower;
    protected int magic;
    protected int constitution;
    protected int strengthModifier;
    protected int dexterityModifier;
    protected int cunningModifier;
    protected int willpowerModifier;
    protected int magicModifier;
    protected int constitutionModifier;

    public int Strength{

        get { return strength + strengthModifier; }
        protected set { strength = value; }
    }

    public int Dexterity{

        get { return dexterity + dexterityModifier; }
        protected set { dexterity = value; }
    }

    public int Cunning{

        get { return cunning + cunningModifier; }
        protected set { cunning = value; }
    }

    public int Willpower{

        get { return willpower + willpowerModifier; }
        protected set { willpower = value; }
    }

    public int Magic{

        get { return magic + magicModifier; }
        protected set { magic = value; }
    }

    public int Constitution{

        get { return constitution + constitutionModifier; }
        protected set { constitution = value; }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Calculated Attribute Field and Property Region
    protected AttributePair health;
    protected AttributePair stamina;
    protected AttributePair mana;

    public AttributePair Health{
        get { return health; }
    }

    public AttributePair Stamina
    {
        get { return stamina; }
    }

    public AttributePair Mana
    {
        get { return mana; }
    }

    protected int attack;
    protected int damage;
    protected int defense;
    #endregion

    #region Level Field and Property Region
    protected int level;
    protected long experience;

    public int Level
    {
        get { return level; }
        protected set { level = value; }
    }

    public long Experience
    {
        get { return experience; }
        protected set { experience = value; }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Constructor Region
    private Entity()
    {
        Strength = 0;
        Dexterity = 0;
        Cunning = 0;
        Willpower = 0;
        Magic = 0;
        Constitution = 0;
        health = new AttributePair(0);
        stamina = new AttributePair(0);
        mana = new AttributePair(0);
    }
    public Entity(EntityData entityData)
    {
        entityType = entityData.EntityName;
        Strength = entityData.Strength;
        Dexterity = entityData.Dexterity;
        Cunning = entityData.Cunning;
        Willpower = entityData.Willpower;
        Magic = entityData.Magic;
        Constitution = entityData.Constitution;
        health = new AttributePair(0);
        stamina = new AttributePair(0);
        mana = new AttributePair(0);
    }
    #endregion
     }
    }
```

And EntityData.cs:

```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;

   public class EntityData
   {
    #region Field Region
    public string ClassName;
    public int Strength;
    public int Dexterity;
    public int Cunning;
    public int Willpower;
    public int Magic;
    public int Constitution;
    public string HealthFormula;
    public string StaminaFormula;
    public string MagicFormula;
    #endregion
    #region Constructor Region
    private EntityData()
     {
    }
      #endregion
       #region Static Method Region
       public static void ToFile(string Classes)
    {
        string toString = EntityName + ", ";
        toString += Strength.ToString() + ", ";
        toString += Dexterity.ToString() + ", ";
                toString += Cunning.ToString() + ", ";
                toString += Willpower.ToString() + ", ";
        toString += Magic.ToString() + ", ";
                toString += Constitution.ToString() + ", ";
                toString += HealthFormula + ", ";
        toString += StaminaFormula + ", ";
                toString += MagicFormula + ", ";

    return toString;
     }
     public static EntityData FromFile(string Classes)
     {
        EntityData entity = new EntityData();
        return entity;
    }
    #endregion
    }
```

I want to pull the formatted data in the file "Classes" and input it into EntityData.cs Variables associated with each other.

Comment: You may want to consider a more rigorous method for storing your data.  Look into XML or JSON.

Comment: You also should work on saving your data to file. Use `StringBuilder` for that, write data somewhere, use your `Classes` parameter, either make method return type to `string`, or do not return string from that method.

Comment: "I want to pull the formatted data in the file "Classes" and input it into EntityData.cs Variables associated with each other."  And what part of this is giving you trouble?  Opening a text file and reading the lines of text?  Parsing a string into name/value pairs?  Assigning these values to properties of an entity?

Answer (score 1):

Use json. It's much, much shorter than XML and therefore, once you get used to it, much easier to read.

With JSON you will be able to view your entire character on one screen, while with XML it'll probably take 10 pages of scrolling.

As for what is json and how to handle it, see this post: [JSON library for C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474377/json-library-for-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

I definitelly suggest storing data in a XML file. It will give you greater flexibility and will be much easier to work with.

If you want to stick with current format, you can manually parse one line this way:

```
// input text
string input = "Name=Fighter, Strength = 10,Cunning = 4, Willpower = 2, Magic = 5, Constitution = 10, Health Formula = 250, Stamina Formula = 200, Magic Formula = 100";

// dictionary with values.. key => value
var dict = input.Split(',').Select(s2 => s2.Replace(" ", "")).ToDictionary(s => s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf('=')), s => s.Substring(s.IndexOf('=') + 1));

// retrieving single values
int willpower = int.Parse(dict["Willpower"]);
...
```

Comment: never used xml, always thought of it as website stuff, never really used it.  I've looked into it, but it seems more to it then simple text parsing, I've seen some examples of serialization but it confuses me. how would it work in the case I suggested above?

Comment: Take a look at this link: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-xml-serialization

You simply create a class holding values (that's your EntityData) and pass it to XmlSerializer to serialize. When deserializing, you provide the type you want to get and XmlSerializer does the rest for you.