# $.ajax() - working with returned json data

Tags: json, jquery

I am unable to extract data form the returned json data from ASP.NET webmethod. Here is my code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "myurl",
    data: "{}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (appdata) {
        console.log(appdata.d);
        var testdata = appdata.d;
        //$.each(testdata, function (index, appt) {
        //    console.log(appt);
        //});
    }
});
```

`console.log(appdata.d)` returned data in following format

```
[
 {
  'PRODUCTID' : '51',
  'ENTRYDATE' : '2/13/2013 12:00:00 AM',
  'CATEGORYID' : ''
 },

 {
  'PRODUCTID' : '52',
  'ENTRYDATE' : '2/13/2013 12:00:00 AM',
  'CATEGORYID' : ''
 }
]
```

code

```
//$.each(testdata, function (index, appt) {
//    console.log(appt);
//});
```

resulted in following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for...
```

How can I extract this data??

**Edit**
`console.log(appdata)` gives the following

```
Object {d: "[{'PRODUCTID' : '51','ENTRYDATE' : '2/13…ENDTIME' : '2/13/2013 3:45:00 AM','CATEGORYID' : ''}]"}
```

Comment: Apart from that, using all-caps property name is probably a bad idea (readability, conventions)

Comment: You get that error if you try to `$.each()` loop through a string (i.e. `console.log()` is showing a string, not an array). The server is not passing you valid JSON or jQuery is not parsing the JSON for some other reason.

Comment: well as soon as I comment out $.each() portion, no exception is returned. As for as all-caps are concerned I am using a method to convert datatable to json and have no idea how these turned into upper but that what I got in console.

Comment: @Juhana jQuery throws a parse error in case of malformed JSON (or, it should)

Comment: @Juhana If I try to `$.each` through a string, I see the string as an array of characters (jQuery 1.7.1)

Comment: @JanDvorak I get the OP's error in 1.9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that if you `console.log( appdata )` you get something like this:

```
{
    d: "[
    {
      'PRODUCTID' : '51',
      'ENTRYDATE' : '2/13/2013 12:00:00 AM',
      'CATEGORYID' : ''
    },
    ..."
}
```

That is, the server is wrapping the array contained in `d` in quotes. The response is valid JSON so jQuery doesn't complain about it, but the value of `d` is not an object but another JSON string.

Either fix the server script so that it doesn't do that, or if that's not possible, parse the string as a separate JSON entity.

Comment: Even so, it should not throw that exception. I can iterate over string with `$.each` easily.

Comment: @juhana thanks.. I guess you are right but since this is the very first time I am working with json I am afraid I didn't get all what you said. How can I parse the string as separate JSON entity.

Comment: @ZedBee `$.parseJson(appdata.d)`

Comment: @JanDvorak but I guess I read something about $.parseJSON that it has issues with values that have single quotes.

Comment: @ZedBee it's because they are _not_ valid JSON. If your javascript literal string has single quotes, you better fix the server. What kind of server generates _that_?

Comment: Yeah, you can't parse the JSON if what you have is not JSON. Fix the server script instead.

Comment: hmmm I think thats the only option I have.. anyways tnx a lot :)

Comment: @ZedBee my question still stands. What kind of standard server generates javascipt literals with single quotes?

Comment: @JanDvorak I am using c# code found on internet which converts Datatable data to JSON

Comment: @ZedBee Can you point me to your source? I want to talk to them.

Comment: yes .. that what I was trying to do .. lemme search it again :)

Comment: Not seeing the code it's hard to say for sure, but chances are you're not using the script right: you should convert the whole output once right before displaying it, now it looks like you're running it multiple times which creates the "JSON inside JSON" situation.

Comment: @Juhana I'm not worried about JSON within JSON within JSON as I am concerned about the single quotes for keys. _These are the library's fault_.

Comment: Here it is .. http://koteswararaon.blogspot.com/2012/06/converting-aspnet-datatable-to-json.html

Comment: I am just calling this code to pass my datatable .. ConvertToJSON(mydt); and passing the returned string back to jquery as it is returned by the ConvertToJSON() method.

Comment: Yeah, that looks like a terrible script. I don't know C# but I'd be surprised if it didn't have actual libraries for JSON. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474377/json-library-for-c-sharp

Comment: well there is one JSON.NET I learned about while searching and thought should try something simpler. Well I guess now would be a good time to explore other standard options

Comment: I've written them a comment linking here (and two meta-comments concerning the forum quality). Let's see how they react.

Comment: Update Jan 11: I have finally returned to check my little comment on that website. Nope, no response, and my comment was gone as well. I am wondering why was it removed. Does the blog post author _want_ to hurt people?