# json deserialization and field extraction?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, deserialization

Following is the response that I'm getting from REST

```
{
    "category_id": 1314,
    "display_category_name": "",
    "english_category_name": "Sports",
    "url_category_name": ""
},
{
    "category_id": 13,
    "display_category_name": "Art",
    "english_category_name": "Art",
    "url_category_name": "art"
},
{
    "category_id": 21,
    "display_category_name": "Blogs",
    "english_category_name": "Blogs",
    "url_category_name": "blogs"
}
```

But I need only "category_id" and `english_category_name` to be displayed  so how can I extract those two fields alone in c# ?

Thanks in advance .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474377/json-library-for-c-sharp, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh674188.aspx

Comment: Entity in C# should contain only this two properties.

Comment: @user2037787 Do you want these properties in C# or jquery?

Comment: @ChiragVidani im ready use anything .. Jquery is also fine for me ..

Comment: Can you brief your problem again? As I think second comment contains answer.

Comment: @ChiragVidani my problem is like i have to display  particular fields from the JSON response .. And i have mentioned the response above

Comment: @user2037787 In my second comment I have already specified that the "Entity in C# should contain only this two properties."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the following class:

```
public class Category
{
    public int category_id { get; set; }
    public string english_category_name { get; set; }
}
```

Use the following library `Newtonsoft.Json`

Deserialize the jsonstring as follows:

```
var categories = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Category>>(json);
```

You can then access the categories as a list of the Category objects i.e

```
var category = categories.FirstOrDefault();
string categoryDisplayName = category.english_category_name;
```

Please note you can also rename the fields in C# from the json types like this:

```
[JsonProperty("english_category_name")]
public string EnglishCategoryName { get; set; }
```

Comment: var category = categories.FirstOrDefault();
string categoryDisplayName = category.display_category_name;   Doesnot  working ?? any other method

Comment: Sorry it should be string categoryDisplayName = category.english_category_name ; I've updated the answer.

Comment: var category = categories.FirstOrDefault() shows error .. Have to include any dll

Answer (score 0):

You can use either `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer` or [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx)