# C# Importing CSV data

Tags: c#, json, csv

I have an interesting integration. A third party is providing a CSV file with various information that I want to use.

My first thoughts are to build a model based on that CSV, by breaking it down, I currently have this in a DataTable.

```
var s = new List<string>();
        s.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines(@"e:\\csvfile.csv"));

        var data = new DataTable();

        var headers = s.First().Split('|');

        foreach(var h in headers)
        {
            data.Columns.Add(h);
        }

        var records = s.Skip(1);

        foreach(var r in records)
        {
            data.Rows.Add(r.Split('|'));
        }
```

Now that bit is fine, I get a nice DataTable i suppose i can extract from and can use to build a "Product" model against. However they include JSON inside the CSV such as.

```
{"product_version_id":"932","product_version_name":"S7"}
```

In my DataTable I get that put into one of the columns, however that information in there would be good to use for the model as well. But I am slightly confused how to extract that to commit it to the Model and ultimately the database via EF.

I haven't before seen JSON 'inside' of a CSV file, so the question really is how can I extract it? To get some idea of the scope of this CSV feed its currently 101 columns by over 2000 rows. That is one provider, there will be 4.

Of those 101 columns I don't really want ALL that data I only need some of it to build a Product model against.

Hopefully some thought on this can be achieved as I'm confused now. Not even sure if a DataTable is the right way anymore!

Thanks peeps :)

Comment: A csv file is just a delimited text file. Read each line and parse it into your Product class yourself. Do an additional parse for the json column and ignore the columns you don't care about. If you don't need pre-processing before import you might get some optimization by writing out a batch SQL insert script and only use EF when you query data out of the table.

Comment: There's not much here that's particularly specific to MVC.

Comment: Hi Jasen, The application is a .NET MVC app. The csv file forms part of the _data_ for the application. This data will be imported into the database and used by EF to then be passed onto the ViewModels and controllers. My question is trying to find the most efficient way to get hold of this not seeing JSON in here before. So if I understand correctly, read each line, split on the character | , and then build the _model_ from the CSV split. Would you put it into a datatable, I did have just a CSV split before...

Comment: `foreach (var product in rawCSV.Skip(1))
            {
                Product p = new Product();
                var csv = new List<string>();
                decimal product_id = 0;
                csv.AddRange(product.Split('|'));

                //lets build the model
               Decimal.TryParse(csv[0], out product_id);
                p.aw_product_id = product_id;
                p.merchant_category = csv[2];`

Comment: It all depends on whether you need to do anything with the data before storing it. Do you care to keep this in a database?  There's no point in constructing objects up-front if are just saving immediately to a database. If you do want to perform some computation before committing then go ahead and `new Product { Id = Convert.ToInt32(col[i]), ... }`. If there's anything specific to `DataTable` that you need then go ahead an use that.

Comment: Thanks Jasen, I think the way before I had it was to split the CSV down, build a product against it. As its coming from a 3rd party I'd want to do some cleaning of 'bad' characters etc. I just wanted something clean whereas breaking down the CSV into [i] chunks doesn't seem too clean, i was thinking DataTable to at least be able to reference a column name etc. Say it has a 'Description' column and i want to put that into a product pulling it from the column in the DataTable called 'Description' seemed better than just saying csv[10] as an example - would you agree. open to opinion on this.

Comment: you may take a look at this question if you ever need to parse your JSON and get the related data http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474377/json-library-for-c-sharp

Comment: Thanks @Vtik - That looks to be a good question.

Comment: I'm actually thinking that the better solution to this is to run their CSV through some serious cleaning first, perhaps into something more 'useful' for the web application such as an XML. Then I know the data I'm importing is actually what i **need** Thanks people.