# How to Serialize Json to Object in C# without use NewtonSoft

Tags: c#

i tried to Serialize a Json to a "x" class, but i can't get this object with values from my Json. I want to do this without use NewtonSoft.
Somebody can help?

```
{"Data":{"RI":{"Node":1,"Subnode":1 }},"RU":{"Node":2,"Subnode":2 }}}



public class RootObject{
    public List<Data> Data {get; set;}


    public static Data Deserialize(string jsonData){
        JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        RootObject rootObj = ser.Deserialize<RootObject>(jsonData);    return rootObj;
    }
}

public class Data{
    public RI RI {get; set;}
    public RU RU {get; set;}
}

public class RI{
    public int Node {get; set;}
    public int Subnode {get; set;}
}
public class RU{
    public int Node {get; set;}
    public int Subnode {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: `I want to do this without use NewtonSoft` Can you talk us through why you don't want to use NewtonSoft?

Comment: This isn't even valid c#. `class` should be lowercase for example and your static method is missing a name (or a return type?) and a return statement

Comment: @mjwills, I can't use NewtonSoft because this DLL it's not allowed in my job.

Comment: Wow. Did they explain **why** you can't use that DLL? Are you not allowed to use **any** DLLs, or just that one? _Sorry to harp on, but hand-rolling your own JSON serializer is insanity._

Comment: All the property names in the json  string are in incorrect case. Also `"Data"` in json string does not represent an array or collection. It's a single property there. So the `RootObject` class should have property `public Data Data {get; set;}`

Comment: I can't use NewtonSoft, any DLL that aren't NewtonSoft yes.

Comment: Honestly, it may be a much better solution to your problem to go back to whoever made the decree that NewtonSoft cannot be used and really discuss that. In this day and age it's just common practice to use frameworks like NewtonSoft to get things done, instead of having to reinvent the wheel every time. Plus, a package such as NewtonSoft has already been throughly debugged, whereas whatever code you write will have its own set of bugs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON library for C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474377/json-library-for-c-sharp)

Comment: This questioner's boss must be a Leibnitz fanboy!  Seriously, everybody who needs to do JSON in C# uses Newtonsoft.  :-) It has the broadly permissive MIT license. And, it works.  If you reinvent the flat tire, you have, well, a flat tire.

Comment: @O.Jones I explained because i can't use NewtonSoft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCF has some JSON stuff in it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-serialize-and-deserialize-json-data

Ya need to adorn your classes with [DataContract] and [DataMember]. Something like this.

```
[DataContract]
public class Data{
    public RI RI {get; set;}
    public RU RU {get; set;}
}

[DataMember]
public class RI{
    public int Node {get; set;}
    public int Subnode {get; set;}
}

[DataMember]
public class RU{
    public int Node {get; set;}
    public int Subnode {get; set;}
}
```

You didn't show your Node and Subnode classes; you will have to make them into `[DataMember]` classes too.

Then you can put the JSON into a stream something like this:

```
var data = new Data();
...
/* populate data somehow or other */
...
MemoryStream str = new MemoryStream();  
DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Person));
...
ser.WriteObject(str, data);   
...
/* read back that stream */
str.Position = 0;  
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(st);  
Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd());   /* or something else useful */
```

More fun than developers should be allowed to have.

Comment: I didn't debug this. Caveat lector.